# connection to a sql server database by ip

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net, connection-string, windows-authentication

I am doing an application that connects to a database located in the same network. the DBMS is SQL Server 2005 and i'd like to test the `ping` to the ip adress and then test the connection to the database by ado.net:

```
 Ping p = new Ping();
            try
            {
                PingReply pingReply6 = p.Send(ip.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("IP: " + pingReply6.Address + " \n Etat : " + pingReply6.Status);
                string connexionString;
                connexionString = @"Data Source=Owner;Initial Catalog=base;Integrated Security=true;";
                IDbConnection connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);
                try { connexion.Open(); MessageBox.Show(" the connection is established "); }
                catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP"); }
```

As you see, i'd like to connect to a database by it adress ip, i test the ping and it works but when i test the connection to my database in my server it isn't working

1. what is the error in the connection string?
2. how can i change the connection string to connect not to my own database but to other database with the indicated adress ip (windows authentification)?

Comment: you are not specifying by IP in the connection string!

Comment: yes, because i test first at all the connection to my database and it failed

Comment: Does your application try the remote sever and if it fails then try the local? If not, your test isn't needed, why see if it can connect and then connect first; just connect because it either will or won't any way!!

Comment: please  see my update, i commited a mistake in the server name. I delete the `.\` and it works now. i need to connect by ip adress to other database located in the same network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might help

```
connexionString = @"Data Source=" + pingReply6.Address +  "\Owner;Initial Catalog=base;Integrated Security=true;";
```

In your above `.` in the connection string means localhost

As @RemusRusanu says IP address is considered poor form however the above will function. hostname would be better

Comment: i try to connect like this `connexionString = @"Data Source=Owner;Initial Catalog=base;Integrated Security=true;";` and it works but when i modify it like that `connexionString = @"Data Source=" + 127.0.0.1 +  "\Owner;Initial Catalog=base;Integrated Security=true;";` it didn't

Comment: @lamloumi CF here, connect via IP address http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 theres a couple of other syntactic options

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx). Assign the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx) property to the server name you want to connect to. Extract the [`ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring.aspx) from the builder when you want to open a connection. This guarantees a correctly formatted connection string.

In general is a bad practice to use the IP. Use the computer name.

Testing for ping is not relevant for connectivity. SQL connection can use protocols that are not related to TCP/IP (eg. shared memory). Ping can fail depending on various corpnet [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) settings. Ping can succeed but connectivity can fail based on firewall and IPSec rules. TCP/IP connectivity does not guarantee T-SQL connectivity.